# ASP.NET .cshtml razor file transform on Build

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, build, transform

I'm trying to find a way to transform my index.cshtml file when building my project.
For instance make this:

```
<script src="app-dev.js"></script>
```

become this when Build mode is `Release`:

```
<script src="app-prod.js></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this will work.

Add an appsetting for it:

```
<add key="Environment" value="dev"/>
```

Then in your view add this:

```
<script src="app-@(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]).js></script>
```

In your other environments simply use transforms to replace it i.e.

```
<appSettings>       
    <add key="Environment" value="prod" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

An alternative and I feel a better approach would be to abstract out the `WebConfiguration` manager as an interface and have the app setting set in a model instead.

If it is in a common layout and set everytime maybe create a base model and have it set in an `OnActionExecuted` in a base controller instead.

Comment: I use the `appsetting` soluion and it working quite well. The only thing is that it works when publishing only, not when launching the app from VS. Thanks.

Comment: @Ludohen Nice one, yes the solution will only work when publishing as it relies on web transforms.

Comment: by the way, how would you declare/access such Env. variable from a controller?

Comment: If you just want access to the web config you can use this in your controller. System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] However as I mention in the answer you may want to abstract it out into an interfaced service to make it more test friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the decision has to be made based on whether the build is debug build or release build. We created a mvc helper extension method as

```
        public static MvcHtmlString CustomScriptTag(this HtmlHelper helper)
        { 
            var scriptString = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' src='{0}'></script>", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/app-prod.js"));

#if DEBUG
            scriptString = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' src='{0}'></script>", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/app-dev.js"));
#endif

            return new MvcHtmlString(scriptString);
       }
```

From your cshtml file you can call it like

```
@Html.CustomScriptTag()
```